# "No Launcher activity " found error in eclipse while running android app

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, launcher

I have wrote a simple code in eclipse.when I tried to run it from emulator I got a message:"Unfortunatlly App is stopped"..And logcat message is "No launcher activity found"..
This is my Android-Manifest.xml file..

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.prolific.pl2303hxdsimpletest"
    android:versionCode="11"
    android:versionName="2.0.2.11" >

    <uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity            
            android:name="com.prolific.pl2303hxdsimpletest.PL2303HXDSimpleTest"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_pl2303_hxdsimple_test"             
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"   
            android:launchMode="singleTop"         
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"  >                              
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />                
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            <!-- action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED"     /> -->              
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
               android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I don't know why this error is coming..Anyone have idea why this error is coming??

Thank you,
Laxmi

Comment: PL2303HXDSimpleTest is example project from prolific. The pre-build app works. I've tried to import the source code into eclipse and I'm experiencing the same error you are. the code uses the android.hardware.usb package in USB Host mode. Information here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html#example the developer docs for this android package. It includes an example Manifest which is similar to the sample code. It also explains the android manifest requirements. Source Code: http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?p_id=230&pcid=41 Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change activity name to

```
android:name=".PL2303HXDSimpleTest"
```

Also, it is a good practice to end the name of the activity with Activity suffix, i.e. MailActivity or MyActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this line:

```
<action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
```

Reason:
Multiple action tags in a single intent-filter tag will cause the error.

Comment: Can you expand upon your answer / explain why this might help?

Comment: I tried to remove the <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />..

Comment: I had a problem close to yours when I declared additional elements in intent-filter in manifest file, so I just thought that it can fix your problem